# Select-Object -ExpandProperty multiple in powershell

Tags: powershell

From REST API call, I try to store the response in csv using below code

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://api.ipstack.com/54.251.51.24?access_key=mykey&security=1&hostname=1' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers |
    Select-Object ip,hostname -ExpandProperty time_zone |
    Select-Object ip,hostname,@{N='time_zone_code';E={$_.code}} -ExpandProperty location |
    Select-Object ip,hostname,time_zone_code,@{N='location_geoname_id';E={$_.geoname_id}} -ExpandProperty languages |
    Select-Object ip,hostname,location_geoname_id,time_zone_code,@{N='languages_native';E={$_.native}} |
        Export-Csv C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Danial\response.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

it gives me below error

```
Select-Object : Property "location" cannot be found.
At line:3 char:9
+         Select-Object ip,hostname,@{N='time_zone_code';E={$_.code}} - ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{id=Australia/...e=1.132.104.84}:PSObject) 
[Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

I tried many things but don't know how to expand multiple property in Select-Object. Rest response is

```
{
    "ip": "54.251.51.24",
    "hostname": "54.251.51.24",
    "type": "ipv4",
    "continent_code": "OC",
    "continent_name": "Oceania",
    "country_code": "AU",
    "country_name": "Australia",
    "region_code": "QLD",
    "region_name": "Queensland",
    "city": "Brisbane",
    "zip": "4000",
    "latitude": -27.467580795288086,
    "longitude": 153.02789306640625,
    "location": {
        "geoname_id": 2174003,
        "capital": "Canberra",
        "languages": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "name": "English",
                "native": "English"
            }
        ],
        "country_flag": "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/au.svg",
        "country_flag_emoji": "",
        "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA",
        "calling_code": "61",
        "is_eu": false
    },
    "time_zone": {
        "id": "Australia/Brisbane",
        "current_time": "2023-03-07T18:54:34+10:00",
        "gmt_offset": 36000,
        "code": "AEST",
        "is_daylight_saving": false
    }
}
```

I want to store all columns of **location** and **time_zone** in csv as readable not System.Object

Comment: See following posting : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/en-US/ab46c8a7-bdc5-4d93-be93-87e7776bc1a9/looking-for-examples-powershell-convertfromjson-where-there-are-multiple-arrays?forum=winserverpowershell&force_isolation=true

Comment: Please add an example of how the expected CSV should look like.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to simply create new objects from the data rows and export those rather than use `Select-Object`:

1. Set up some test data

```
$json = @"
{
    "ip": "54.251.51.24",
    "hostname": "54.251.51.24",
    "type": "ipv4",
    "continent_code": "OC",
    "continent_name": "Oceania",
    "country_code": "AU",
    "country_name": "Australia",
    "region_code": "QLD",
    "region_name": "Queensland",
    "city": "Brisbane",
    "zip": "4000",
    "latitude": -27.467580795288086,
    "longitude": 153.02789306640625,
    "location": {
        "geoname_id": 2174003,
        "capital": "Canberra",
        "languages": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "name": "English",
                "native": "English"
            }
        ],
        "country_flag": "https://assets.ipstack.com/flags/au.svg",
        "country_flag_emoji": "",
        "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA",
        "calling_code": "61",
        "is_eu": false
    },
    "time_zone": {
        "id": "Australia/Brisbane",
        "current_time": "2023-03-07T18:54:34+10:00",
        "gmt_offset": 36000,
        "code": "AEST",
        "is_daylight_saving": false
    }
}
"@

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

2. Format the data into a csv-friendly format

```
$formatted = $data | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{
        "HostName" = $_.hostname
        "Capital"  = $_.location.capital
        "Timezone" = $_.time_zone.code
    }
}

# show the data for reference:
$formatted | format-table

# HostName     Capital  Timezone
# --------     -------  --------
# 54.251.51.24 Canberra AEST
```

3. Convert the formatted data (use `Export-Csv` instead if you're saving to disk):

```
$formatted | ConvertTo-Csv

# "HostName","Capital","Timezone"
# "54.251.51.24","Canberra","AEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error on accessing `location` because you already got rid of this property here:

`Select-Object ip,hostname -ExpandProperty time_zone |`

Add properties that you'll be using down the pipeline to all preceding `select-object`

Answer (score 0):

My issue resolved using below code

```
$properties=@('ip','hostname'
    @{Name='time_zone_code';Expression={$_.time_zone.code}}
    @{Name='location_geoname_id';Expression={$_.location.geoname_id}}
    @{Name='location_languages_native';Expression={$_.location.languages.native}}
)
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://api.ipstack.com/54.251.51.24?access_key=mykey&security=1&hostname=1' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers |
    Select-Object -Property $properties |
        Export-Csv C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Danial\response.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```